# Link two Flatlist React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

A screen has 2 Flatlist like the picture, I want to make a link between to both Flatlist, when I press an item on Flatlist 1, Flatlist 2 scrolls to the position of this item and when I scroll Flatlist 2, Flatlist 1 active item was scrolled to.
Can guys give me the keyword or an code example of this function? Thanks for all <3

[image]

Comment: what does it mean : "when I choose an item on Flatlist 1"  ?? you mean you press on that item? because if you want an action to be called in onPress, this will be easier to answer

Comment: Yes, I mean press on it, sorry for my English :(

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to solve this problem. First you can bind the on item selection event and when the item is selected you can use the following code for list. Create the 2 refs one for each list and then on select scroll to other lists index.

```
this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({ animated: true, index: <YOUR INDEX> });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<FlatList
    ref={(list) => this.myFlatList = list}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
       <TouchableOpacity
           onPress={()=>this.myFlatList.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index});}
       />
    );}
    ....
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a ref to your second flat list,

```
ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
```

then FlatList has a method scrollToIndex, get the index of first FlatList clicked item pass it to the scrollToIndex of second FlatList